# urxvt -e doesn't source .zshrc

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, zsh, path

I want to create a key binding for the common task: open a new terminal window and open the program `ranger` in it.

The obvious command would be something like that:

```
urxvt -e ranger
```

The important things work right out of the box. But in `ranger` I want to use a different program called `fzf`, and this program is not found. The error message `zsh:1: command not found: fzf`.

Same result with

```
urxvt -e zsh -c ranger
```

When I already have an opened terminal and call `ranger` in it, then `fzf` can be called without any problems.

I took a look, and the path to the binary of `fzf` gets added to `$PATH` in my `.zshrc`. So my assumption is that this never sources my `.zshrc`, and it never gets added to the path.

---

There is an obvious fix for this (call `fzf` inside `ranger` using the full path `~/.fzf/bin/fzf`), but this problem annoyed me quite a few times already, and I want a nice solution.

How can I open a new terminal, that sources `.zshrc` and opens the program `ranger`?

---

One more observation that I don't understand:

I created a script `myranger.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
source ~/.zshrc
ranger
```

and created the new terminal with:

```
urxvt -e myranger.sh
```

The terminal with ranger opens, but `fzf` is still not in `$PATH`.
What did I miss here?

---

Btw, this is not `zsh` or `urxvt` specific. I also tested this with `bash` and/or `gnome-terminal`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`urxvt -e zsh -c ranger` is pretty much equivalent to `urxvt -e ranger`. You're telling urxvt to run zsh, and zsh to run ranger, and that's it. `urxvt -e zsh -c ranger` does not load `.zshrc`: zsh only loads it when starting an *interactive* shell, i.e. a shell that reads user commands, not when starting a shell that runs a script (whether this script is in a file, or passed on the command line with `-c`).

You can load `.zshrc` explicitly (`urxvt -e zsh -c '. ~/.zshrc; ranger'`, or use a wrapper script as you did). This isn't a good idea though, because `.zshrc` is for interactive settings of zsh — key bindings, aliases, etc. Environment variable settings (e.g. PATH) apply to all programs, so they should be done at login time, [usually in `~/.profile`](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980#183980). Move your PATH setting from `.zshrc` to `.profile` where it belongs.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting `zsh` manual:

> INVOCATION
>
> -i Force shell to be interactive.

and later

> If the shell is a login shell, commands are read from `/etc/zprofile` and then `$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile`.  Then, if  the  shell is  interactive,  commands  are  read  from  `/etc/zshrc`  and  then  `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc`. Finally, if the shell is a login shell, `/etc/zlogin` and `$ZDOTDIR/.zlogin` are read.
>
> ...
>
> If `ZDOTDIR` is unset, `HOME` is used instead.

---

So, to force sourcing `.zshrc` at start run

```
urxvt -e zsh -ci ranger
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `-ic`? Otherwise, wouldn't the command be `i ranger`?

Comment: @SolomonUcko doesn't matter, will work both ways.